# How to set different bits in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to use bit operations in VBA. For example I want to set first bit in 0 second bit in 1 and so on. How can I do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/bit-operations.shtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use masks.

If you want to set* the `n-th` bit, you can perform an `Or` operation of your original value and a mask filled with `0` **except** for the `n-th` position.

That way, `1100 Or 0001` will set the first bit resulting in `1101`. `1100 Or 0010` will set the second bit, resulting in `1110`.

If you want to unset* the `n-th` position, you can do the opposite. Perform an `And` operation on your original value with a mask filled with `1` **except** the `n-th` position.

That way, `0011 And 1110` will unset the first bit resulting in `0010`, `0011 And 1101` will unset the second bit, resulting in `0001`.

* Set means to turn the bit into 1. Unset means to turn the bit into 0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If i want to make e.g. `00001101` I need to do it like this: `1 Or &HC`. Are there any other variants, because I need to use function and its arguments are numbers of bits, that should be set.

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of bits that should be set"? Randomly? Or do you receive the "n-th" bit that should be set?

Comment: Yes, I receive the n-th bit.

Comment: So to create your mask dynamically you will need bit-shifting. VBA does not have this built-in, like other languages. But you can emulate it by multiplying 1 by a power of 2. So.. if you calculate `1 * 2 ^ n` you will have a mask with `1` on the `n-th` position. (Make sure you treat border-cases, such as shifting by a number of bits that your computer cannot support)

Comment: I understood. I can make OR AND statement with this information. Thanks for help!