# Overflow runtime error 6 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know what I have done wrong in my code. I already changed everything to Long and I still get the overflow error. Please help. The line:

```
Binary = Binary + Generation(i, j) * 10 ^ (j - 1)
```

Has been highlighted yellow.

Full code:

```
Dim Generation() As Long
Dim Fitness() As Long
Dim i, j As Long
Dim Binary As Long
Dim Binary2 As Long
Dim Initial As Long
Dim x, y As Long

Private Sub ButtonGeneratePopulation_Click()

Initial = Val(InitialPopulation.Value)

ReDim Generation(Initial, 30) As Long
Randomize

For i = 1 To Initial
    For j = 1 To 30
        If Rnd > 0.5 Then
            Generation(i, j) = 1
        Else
            Generation(i, j) = 0
        End If
    Next j
Next i



For i = 1 To Initial
Binary = 0
    For j = 1 To 30
        Binary = Binary + Generation(i, j) * 10 ^ (j - 1)
    Next j
    Cells(i, 1) = Binary
Next i

InitialPopulation.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Comment: With `j` going up to `30`, `Generation(i, j) * 10 ^ (j - 1)` will be very well beyond the [range for `Long`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: How should I change it so that it works?

Comment: Use smaller numbers? Use a data type that can hold the biggest number you might have?

Comment: I have just started using VBA so I am not exactly sure what to use. Where must i use smaller numbers and which data type should I use then?

Comment: Instead  long , use double.

Comment: You know what you are calculating in `Generation(i, j) * 10 ^ (j - 1)`. You know whether or not it would be fine for your logic to make this number smaller. You can see the link above that tells you which numbers each of the available data types can hold. This is all information you need to make a decision, being new to VBA is then hardly an excuse.

Comment: And if it then says unable to get the Bin2Dec worksheet property class? I tried using CDbl instead of Int but it still wont work
    x = Int(WorksheetFunction.Bin2Dec(Binary))

Comment: So your `Binary` was supposed to be a bitmask, but you stored each bit as a decimal digit, and then you would pass that number to `Bin2Dec` that would implicitly convert it to a string first and then convert to an actual decimal. Obviously that would not work with `Double`, but it should not have been done that way to begin with. If you need to store individual bits in `Binary`, [just do so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33416856/11683), and you will not need `Bin2Dec`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Generation() As Long
Dim Fitness() As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Binary As Double '<~~~ this is double
Dim Binary2 As Long
Dim Initial As Long
Dim x As Long, y As Long

Private Sub ButtonGeneratePopulation_Click()

Initial = Val(InitialPopulation.Value)



ReDim Generation(Initial, 30) As Long
Randomize

For i = 1 To Initial
    For j = 1 To 30
        If Rnd > 0.5 Then
            Generation(i, j) = 1
        Else
            Generation(i, j) = 0
        End If
    Next j
Next i



For i = 1 To Initial
Binary = 0
    For j = 1 To 30
        Binary = Binary + Generation(i, j) * 10 ^ (j - 1)
    Next j
    Cells(i, 1) = Binary
Next i

InitialPopulation.Enabled = False

End Sub
```